# Multiple Facebook/Twitter/LinkedIn share images for different content on single page

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, facebook

Throughout one page I have important content that needs to be shared. When someone decides to share one of these sections I need to grab the custom image and text for that specific piece of content. This content needs to be shareable via Facebook, Twitter and LinkedIn.

However I'm struggling to define this as I usually only do one image per page using `meta property` in the head of my page.

If the content didnt have an image attached I would normally use a sharer link such as: `<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://google.co.uk&t=Google">Facebook Share</a>`. However to my knowledge you cannot define an image this way?

I'm pretty sure that I need to customise the `meta property og:image` to change depending on what piece of content is clicked but I'm not sure? I've seen a few different answers to this question but nothing definitive.

Just to clarify what I'm after I've mocked up a quick example with cats! 
Each section would share their defined cat image and heading.

[image]

The site is a PHP Wordpress site, but its not the posts. Its just content on a single page.

Comment: clearify your question

Comment: Suggestion: Use Iframe

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a parameter in the URL and switch the `og:image` parameter serverside depending on the parameter - or you can use the `FB.ui` Feed Dialog with a custom picture: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog

Comment: URL parameters would make them different URLs though, so that all likes/shares/comments would be split between them.